# Texstudio autocomplete figure environment, insert expected content

Tags: floats, texstudio, includegraphics, auto-completion

Using texstudio when I being to write `\begin{figure}` of course it introduces some autocomplete possibilities.

That being said, when I choose `\begin{figure}[placement]...` it only writes

```latex
\begin{figure}[placement]
    content...
\end{figure}
```

Is there any way to configure it to place in typical commands, e.g.

```latex
\begin{figure}[placement]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width]{path}
    \caption{text}
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}
```

or something like this.

Comment: Why don't you use `Wizards / Insert Graphic`?

Comment: I prefer using the keyboard as much as possible. I think it just feels faster/more efficient. That being said I wasn't aware of the wizard, given that the file path doesn't seem to support suggestions upon `ctrl+space` like text does I can't really see myself using it.